# cannot resolve symbol ConfigSlurper and XmlSlurper after upgrade to AS 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, xmlslurper

I get `cannot resolve symbol` errors for `ConfigSlurper` and `XmlSlurper` in my build.gradle after upgrading Android Studio to 3.0, does it require code changes in the new AS? or any replacement for them?

Attach error screenshots:

[image]

[image]